# registerAdapter: register different adapter for different types

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm trying to use different adapters for different types. RESTAdapter and FixtureAdapter. Normally, we can register a different adapter for a specific type such as:

```
DS.Store.registerAdapter('App.Foo', DS.FixtureAdapter.extend());

App.store = DS.Store.create({
    revision: 11,
    //adapter: 'DS.FixtureAdapter'   
    adapter: DS.RESTAdapter.create();
    })
});
```

However, This doesn't seem to work though the tests provided with ember-data suggest exactly the same settings to use different adapter for different types.

```
test("Adapters can be registered on a per-type basis", function() {
  expect(2);

  var Store = DS.Store.extend(),
      Post = DS.Model.extend(),
      Comment = DS.Model.extend();

  Store.registerAdapter(Post, DS.Adapter.extend({
    find: function(store, type, id) {
      strictEqual(type, Post, "Post adapter was used to find Post record");
    }
  }));

  var store = Store.create({
    adapter: DS.Adapter.extend({
      find: function(store, type, id) {
        strictEqual(type, Comment, "default adapter is used to find Comment");
      }
    })
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug report for this: [Per-type Adapter not respected in case of `commit`](https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/616)